# XML Deserialization handle empty tags with Default values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I want to handle the datetime during deserialize. If xml has no node or empty value then I need to set the value to default value of datetime min value or max value based on i have set. So problem here is if xml has `startdate` with empty value like `<startdate></startdate>` then i get null instead of DateTime.MinValue. Similarly i may have some other node such as `enddate` which requires DateTime.MaxValue as default value. If i don't pass the tag `startdate` then I am getting Minvalue which is expected. So how I can handle for empty tags. I need to get Date Minvalue in case of empty tag as well.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Program t = new Program();
        
        t.DeserializeObject("<OrderedItem><startdate>20210125</startdate><enddate>20210324</enddate></OrderedItem>");
        t.DeserializeObject("<OrderedItem></OrderedItem>");
        t.DeserializeObject("<OrderedItem><startdate></startdate><enddate></enddate></OrderedItem>"); //In this case i am getting issue, Output will not have default Min and Max Values
}

  private void DeserializeObject(string testData)
    {
        // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer.
        XmlSerializer serializer =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));

        // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
        OrderedItem i;
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(testData))
        {
            i = (OrderedItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    Console.Write("Start date is "+i.Startdate.Date+"\n");
    Console.Write("End date is "+i.Enddate.Date+"\n\n");
    
    }

public class OrderedItem
{
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "startdate")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "0001-01-01T00:00:00")]
 public CustomDateTime Startdate { 
        get; 
        set;
    } = new CustomDateTime { Date = DateTime.MinValue };

 [XmlElement(ElementName = "enddate")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "9999-12-31T00:00:00")]
 public CustomDateTime Enddate { 
        get; 
        set;
    } = new CustomDateTime { Date = DateTime.MaxValue };
}
```

And in my CustomDateTime I am using IXmlSerializable and below is portion of code

```
public class CustomDateTime : IXmlSerializable, IComparable, IComparable<DateTime>
{
    static string[] formats = new string[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   // here i have CompareTo and other methods which implements interface
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        string input = reader.ReadString();

        DateTime inputDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out inputDate))
        {
            Date = inputDate;
        }
        else
        {
            Date = null;
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (Date != null)
        {
            writer.WriteString(Date.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

Start date is 1/25/2021 12:00:00 AM
End date is 3/24/2021 12:00:00 AM

Start date is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
End date is 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Start date is
End date is

**Expected Output**

Start date is 1/25/2021 12:00:00 AM
End date is 3/24/2021 12:00:00 AM

Start date is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
End date is 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Start date is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
End date is 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Fiddle:https://dotnetfiddle.net/qv7sjP

I thought I can add defaultvalue attribute like `[DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "0001-01-01T00:00:00")]` or `[DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "9999-12-31T00:00:00")]` as required to property `Startdate` and `Enddate` and read this in `ReadXml` method and then set Date property in ReadXml method when tag not present(else block). I am not sure how i can read this and handle it. Also i am not sure is this appropriate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
    public class OrderedItem
    {
        private DateTime _Startdate = new DateTime();
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "startdate")]
        public DateTime Startdate { 
            get{ return _Startdate;} 
            set{ _Startdate = value;}
        }

        private DateTime _Enddate = new DateTime();
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "enddate")]
        public DateTime Enddate
        {
            get { return _Enddate; }
            set { _Enddate = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using CustomDate class not Datetime. But as per your suggestions i modified my code using CustomDate and it won't resolve the original issue. See fiddle for reference https://dotnetfiddle.net/K5Z9gR . I have created this based on the suggestions you provided, Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong

Comment: I would make the default constructor in CustomDateTime  new DateTime : public CustomDateTime() { Date = new DateTime();}

Comment: Ok. But I don't want current datetime to be default value. I want either DateTime minvalue or maxvalue based on my property. I have specified them in question too. In the code shared in question i have taken 3 sample XML inputs. I am facing issue in 3 rd case

Comment: new DataTime() is 1/1/01.  public CustomDateTime(DateTime date) { Date = date;}

Comment: Ok. If I do this. both start and end date will.have same default date of 1/1/01. But I wanted to set different default (mentioned in question and I was trying min and max values). Also my issue happens when XML is having empty value node. So this is happening after the value is set in constructor. So that value will be overwritten with empty in my case. From the fiddle shared in question i am able to reproduce the issue. I feel you have not understood my original issue mentioned in question. Let me know If i am missing something or if I need to rewrite the question appropriately.

Comment: My code work if you pass the constructor with the DataTime d = DataTime.Parse("9999-12-31T00:00:00");

Comment: But for this input it wont work,  t.DeserializeObject("<OrderedItem><startdate></startdate><enddate></enddate></OrderedItem>");   This was my issue i mentioned before. So even if we pass from constructor for empty node inputs it will overwrite and give null values see https://dotnetfiddle.net/K5Z9gR Refer the output and it doesn't show start and end dates

Comment: Then in my code above change : "set{ _Startdate = value;}" To set{ if(value != null({_Startdate = value;}}

Comment: Nice, i updated my code to `set{ if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Date.ToString())){_Startdate = value;}}` as i was using CustomDate class and it worked as expected. Also using DateTime.MnValue and Maxvalue instead of hardcoded values so that code is neat. Now working as expected. Here is the woking code https://dotnetfiddle.net/Da41LT (If you update this fiddle link in answer it may help others too). Thanks a lot for your help.